# Error "is not a JSONObject": an API that returns this format in a String. How can I read and create objects from this with Java?

Tags: java, json, api, rest, arraylist

It's the request: `https://api-pub.bitfinex.com/v2/candles/trade:1h:tBTCUSD/hist?limit=2`
It's the response:

> [[1607630400000,18399,18415,18450.367075,18399,279.63699634],
> [1607626800000,18290.48824022,18399,18400,18255,190.53601166]]

In another post, somebody told me that this is a Json... but when I try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String url = "https://api-pub.bitfinex.com/v2/candles/trade:1h:tBTCUSD/hist?limit=2";
    try {
        URL urlObj = new URL(url);
    
        HttpURLConnection conexion2 = (HttpURLConnection) urlObj.openConnection();
        conexion2.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "UTF-8");
        conexion2.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conexion2.connect();
        InputStreamReader in2 = new InputStreamReader(conexion2.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(in2);
        String output;
        output = br2.readLine();
        JSONArray array = new JSONArray(output);

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(0);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

the Output is:

> org.json.JSONException: JSONArray[0] is not a JSONObject.

Maybe I don't need to convert this String to Json? But how can I convert this String to Array or List?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi there, you are just getting an array, JSON must be a representation of structured data, usually, you have something like {value: [array], value2: { title: 'another object'}}. in this case, you just have an array of arrays

Comment: Excelente, i think so too... but, now... how can i convert this String to Array? sorry i know its easy but im new in Java...

Comment: I don't get that error running the line `JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);` where `response` is the data you've given.  That code runs fine for me.  However, if I add the line `JSONObject obj = array.getJSONObject(0);` then I do get the error you report.  Please edit your question to include the code where the error is thrown: it is definitely not thrown on the line you mention.

Comment: you're right!! look the new code please!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your response

> [[1607630400000,18399,18415,18450.367075,18399,279.63699634],
> [1607626800000,18290.48824022,18399,18400,18255,190.53601166]]

You do not have a json object inside the jsonArray, you have another json array. Here is a code snippet that will work. You have to get a JSONArray inside the look and then get the elements inside the inner array. This is my understanding of what you are trying to achieve.

```
String output = "[[1607630400000,18399,18415,18450.367075,18399,279.63699634], [1607626800000,18290.48824022,18399,18400,18255,190.53601166]]";
    JSONArray array = new JSONArray(output);
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
        JSONArray arr = array.getJSONArray(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < arr.length(); j++) {
            if( arr.get(j) instanceof Double )
                System.out.println(arr.getDouble(j));
            else if( arr.get(j) instanceof Long )
                System.out.println(arr.getLong(j));
            else if( arr.get(j) instanceof String )
                System.out.println(arr.getString(j));
            else
                System.out.println(arr.get(j));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks you very much!!! now i have an other problem... jejeje some times the values come with decimal and sometimes dont... if i cast to Double, and it didnt came with decimal i cant do it... do you undertand?

Comment: @MatiasSolana I have updated the answer above. You can use instanceof to see the type of value and then instead of printing add your logic